# How to animate the value of an UILabel when a UIButton is pressed inside on a UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I've been trying to animate the value of an UILabel once the user presses a UIButton inside my UITableViewCell.

The thing is, in every cell I've placed two buttons (+ and -) that change the amount of that particular item the user has. the problem is that I need to let the user know that the amount changed when he clicked on it. The client wants some kind of animation on the number indicating the quantity every time the user hit the button.

Comment: What have you already tried? Have you tried 'setAnimationWithDuration' or anything similar?

Comment: yes, I tried 'setAnimationWithDuration' but it doesn't seems to work. please if anybody could post a sample code it would be great. thanks